# Show divs with certain classes based on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm trying to build the following functionality:

The webpage has checkboxes that define characteristics of movies, for example "comedy", "drama", "english", "spanish". When the user clicks on one of the checkboxes, divs that have the same class will get displayed on the page.

Here's the part I'm having trouble implementing in a sensible way:
If the user selects a second checkbox, the displayed divs should get "filtered" some more. In other words, if the user has first selected "drama" and then "english", only those divs that have *both* classes should remain visible.

Here is my code so far (it will simply toggle the "comedy" div on/off):

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Movies</title>
    <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">

        <div id="heading">
            <h1 class="inline">Movies</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="selections">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="comedy">Comedy</input></label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="drama">Drama</input></label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="english">English</input></label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="spanish">Spanish</input></label>
        </div>

        <div id="movies">
            <div class="comedy english">Comedy in english.. content</div>
            <div class="comedy spanish">Comedy in spanish.. content</div>
            <div class="drama spanish">Drama in spanish.. content</div>
            <div class="drama english">Drama in english.. content</div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#movies div').toggle(); //hides movie content in the beginning

            $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
                if($(this).attr("value")=="comedy"){
                $('.comedy').toggle();
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps simpler solution

http://jsfiddle.net/goqqosf8/2/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#movies div').hide(); //hides movie content in the beginning

     $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
         select()
     })
 });

function select()
{
    $('#movies div').hide();

    var $div=$('#movies div');
    var check=false;    
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
            var css=$(this).val();                    
            $div=$div.filter('.'+css);

        check=true;
    })

    if(check==true) $div.show();    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Selecting this answer because it's more simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $movies = $('#movies div').hide(); //hides movie content in the beginning

  var $checks = $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    if ($checks.filter(':checked').length) {
      //use the types to gilter them
      var $selected = filter($movies, '.genre');
      $selected = filter($selected, '.language');
      $selected.show();
      $movies.not($selected).hide()
    } else {
      $movies.hide()
    }
  });

  function filter($src, type) {
    var selection = $checks.filter(type + ':checked').map(function() {
      return '.' + this.value;
    }).get();
    console.log(type, $src, selection)
    return selection.length ? $src.filter(selection.join(',')) : $src;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="heading">
      <h1 class="inline">Movies</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="selections">
      <!--Add a type class to the checkboxes-->
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="comedy" class="genre">Comedy</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="drama" class="genre">Drama</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="english" class="language">English</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="spanish" class="language">Spanish</label>
    </div>
    <div id="movies">
      <div class="comedy english">Comedy in english.. content</div>
      <div class="comedy spanish">Comedy in spanish.. content</div>
      <div class="drama spanish">Drama in spanish.. content</div>
      <div class="drama english">Drama in english.. content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```